# How to define a enum 2-D array in java?

Tags: java

This is giving an error for me. I assumed this is syntactically correct. I have no experience with java. Only C++. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
private enum Site{
    OPEN, BLOCKED }
Site[][] grid;

final Site DEFAULT_STATE = Site.OPEN;
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public GridClass(int N)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; i++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = DEFAULT_STATE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the second loop, is it supposed to be "i++" not "j++"?

Comment: I assume you have a main method somewhere? (`public static void main(String[] args)`)

Comment: it is j++ (sorry editing mistake i think), I have main method. I posted the code where I'm getting the problem. I'll try to be more clear from now on.

Comment: side note:  avoid the second look, and use Arrays.fill() method for the second array dimension:  Arrays.fill(grid[i], DEFAULT_STATE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only declaring `grid`, you're not defining it.

You'll need something like:

```
Site[][] grid = new Site[N][N];
```

Comment: Code outside of a method? It _is_ valid, isn't it?

Comment: Where's the code outside a method? Assuming this is all in a class, this is all valid (the `for` loop is in a constructor).

Comment: @ZoveGames This code would be valid outside of a method. It would declare a field `grid` and initialize it. The intention, however, was to put it in the constructor.

Comment: @ZoveGames: Code outside a method is not valid. However, you can enclose it in braces `{ }` to create an *anonymous method* (or even use `static { }` to create a *static anonymous method*).

Comment: All this code is wrapped inside a class if that's what you mean.

Comment: @WChargin `Site[][] grid = new Site[N][N];` as a field initializer is allowed directly in the `class` block.

Comment: @ZoveGames: Yes, I understand. I mean code that isn't a field initializer.

Comment: @veer  It's not valid, because N is not declared in the scope of the field initializer.  This array needs to be instantiated in the constructor.

Comment: @Matt yes, I assumed that went without saying.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're accessing `grid` without having allocated memory to it yet.

Add this as the first line in your constructor:

```
grid = new Site[N][N];
```

The error you're receiving is called a `NullPointerException` because the `grid[i][j]` line is attempting to dereference the null pointer that is `grid`.

---

In addition, your second for loop says `i++`; it should be `j++`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the array in the constructor, since that's where you know the dimensions.  This cannot be done in a static initializer, since N is not in scope at that point.

```
public GridClass(int N) {
   grid = new Site[N][N];
   for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
      Arrays.fill(grid[i], DEFAULT_STATE);
   }
}
```